# Is there a roadmap to learning representation theory of finite group over finite field?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modular-representation-theory

I've been wanted to learn some basic theories of the (non-semisimple) representation of the finite group over a finite field.

I have been guessing that the materials might be contained in the books on $\textbf{the modular representation theory}$.

So I once tried to read the recent book of Peter Schneider.

But it seems that in the book, lots of background materials are presented, the theories on the complete local commutative integral domain, theory of blocks and so on.

What I want to say is that maybe the modular representation theory is deep and difficult, so those prerequisite algebraic theories might be necessary. The problem is that I cannot be sure of whether I can find a tool useful in studying the representation of finite group over $\textbf{a finite field}$.

Now I can also guess that the 'concept' of representation theory over finite field is elementary but very difficult in 'practice', as usual in most field of mathematics.

I think the representation over a finite field is more natural and maybe more interesting (even though it might be naive) than the representation over complete local field. Thus I think there might be other mathematicians who are not specialists in modular representation theory and have the same question.

'Does the modular representation theory give us a tool to study the representation theory of finite group over a finite field?'

If so, then is there some direct reference that focuses on some (even though past) application to the representation over finite field not covering the hot and deep theoretical issues of the modular representation theory?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Honestly speaking, I cannot understand the slightest bit of what you're asking, but I have a feeling that this www.researchgate.net/publication/268247317_Two_More_Variations_on_the_Triangular_Theme paper may be somewhat interesting for your taste.

Comment: @DenisT.  Thank you very much for your interest. I just wanted to know 'in advance' whether the theories of the modular representation theory is and can be used to study the representation over finite field? (Maybe by using the fact that for any finite field F, there is a local field whose residue field is F?)

Comment: There are some groups, for example, the symmetric group, where the representation theory is mostly the same over $\mathbb{F}_p$ as over its algebraic closure. But still it is  sometimes necessary to use the algebraic closure or to work with representations defined over rings such as the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in order to use more general results. For example idempotent lifting and the $cde$-triangle are useful in the symmetric group and need the theory of $p$-modular systems.

Comment: @MarkWildon Thank you very much for your answer! I think I need the representation of $S_{n} \times C_{p^{m}}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ where $S_{n}$ is the symmetric group of order $n$ and $C_{p^{m}}$ is the cyclic group of order $p^{m}$. Cyclic Groups might also be the groups you referred in the beginning of your answer. Writing this answer, I realized that I don't know yet how does the modular representation theory resolves the problems made by the non-semi-simplicity. Can you please recommend me some 'short' references that gives a big picture of the goal of modular representation theory?

Comment: @MarkWildon I guess and hope there are some expositions in the style of the book of Curtis and Reiner that is rather 'abstract' and 'algebraic' and most importantly 'short' that explains the main concepts developed to study the structure of the non-semisimple group ring. Are there? Instead of about how to compute something (which I don't know yet but is important in this theory) I want to know what is the point of knowing something (maybe block?). Thank you again!

Comment: Most of modular representation theory is about the representation theory over a splitting field for the group.  In positive characteristic you can get  a finite splitting field by adjoining to the prime field a primitive mth root of unity where M is the lcm of the orders of p regular elements

Comment: The blocks come about because the group algebra is not semisimple.  You can write it as a direct product of blocks and each indecomposable is an indecomposable of a block

Comment: The complete local ring stuff comes up in trying to relate the characteristic 0 theory to the characteristic p theory.  The idea is as suggested in the comments to view your finite field as the residue field of a complete local domain like the p-adics and then got to the algebraic closure of the field of fractions and use the characters over this field to relate then to characters over the finite field by idempotent lifting.  I think Brauer characters can also be done in a more ad hoc but less conceptual way but I am not an expert

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you very much! for your comments. I'm interested in computing group cohomology. I guess I can search by myself basic materials on the behavior of the blocks under the homomorphism and so on. If you have some good reference on that I would love to know that.  Thank you again!

Comment: To be honest I'm not an expert on this.  Benson has a two book series on representation theory and group cohomology.  The first book does group representation theory and the second uses it in group cohomology.  The first book uses all the fancy machinery and can be a bit brief if you have never seen this stuff.   You might flip through the second book on cohomology to get an idea how the first book machinery is used to see why it is useful

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I've heard of the book but I didn't know that the book has the second volume. Thank you very much for the nice introduction! Your comments were very helpful!

Comment: I often use Benson's two books as a reference. But I don't think they are a good place to learn the material. There are three paths to modular representation theory: character theoretic (Brauer characters, blocks via orthogonality, e.g. Navarro's book), modules (vertices, Green correspondence, blocks, e.g. Alperin's book), rings (orders, number theory, idempotents, blocks, e.g. Puig's book or the two volumes of Curtis and Reiner, Methods of representation theory). Any might be to your taste, but Alperin's book Local representation theory is rightly admired and gets quickly to deep results.

Comment: If you have a specific question about $S_n  \times C_{p^n}$, it might do better on this site than your current question, which seems a bit vague to me. It's the nature of mathematical literature to be difficult and specialised, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MarkWildon Thank you very much for your suggestions. Can you tell me the name of the book of Puig? To be specific, I'm interested in calculating the 0-th Tate cohomology $\hat{H}^{0}(C_{p^{m}},\mathbb{F}_{p}[S_{n}\times C_{p^{m}}]/\mathbb{F}_{p}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n} \times C_{p^{m}}}\sigma )$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{p}[S_{n}\times C_{p^{m}}]$ denotes the group ring and the slash means the quotient, $\mathbb{F}_{p}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}\times C_{p^{m}}}\sigma$ means the vector space spanned by the norm element.

Comment: Sorry, I was misremembering. Külshammer wrote a book with elements of Puig's theory of locally pointed groups, https://www.cambridge.org/9780521405652. Also Thévenaz's book is good for this. I suggest you post your question about cohomology separately. The term 'norm element' isn't so standard to me, but I can see you are quotienting out by the trivial submodule of the group algebra.

Comment: @MarkWildon  Thank you for the correction! As you have understood, by the norm element, I have meant the summation of all the elements of the group. Actually this problem dawned on me very recently, so I will take time to think about this and consider posting it as a question. Thank you very much for the suggestion!